# How to display information in a PyQT Widget imported from Qt Designer

Tags: python, xml, qt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I have the following sample code loading a Qt Designer XML file and displaying it in python

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
import sys

class Ui(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('Weather.ui', self)
        self.show()

app = QApplication([])
window = Ui()
app.exec()
```

That is loading a simple 2 tab window, the XML string where I care about displaying information in the window:

```
   <widget class="QWidget" name="current">
    <attribute name="title">
     <string>Current</string>
    </attribute>
   </widget>
```

How do I input or display information within that widget? Im assuming its a subtype of the window object.
When using Tkinter it was as simple as

```
 tk.Label("String")
```

I feel like I jumped 3 or 4 steps and am having trouble articulating how to ask or word what I want so I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Found out I could just use

```
pyuic5 weather.ui
```

to show me how the XML is built in python code, which I can use to figure it out myself.